# How to merge lists of dictionaries (JSONs) in Python?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary

I have two lists of dictionaries that I get from JSON: first one is a list of all objects, and the second list is objects with name = Disk:

```
list_of_dicts1 = [
 {u'id' : u'111',
  u'host' : u'host01',
  u'name' : u'Disk'},

 {u'id' : u'222',
  u'host' : u'host02',
  u'name' : u'Disk'},

 {u'id' : u'333',
  u'host' : u'host02',
  u'name' : u'CPU'}
]

list_of_dicts2 = [
 {u'id' : u'111',
  u'host' : u'host01',
  u'name' : u'Disk'},

 {u'id' : u'444',
  u'host' : u'host02',
  u'name' : u'Disk'},

 {u'id' : u'555',
  u'host' : u'host03',
  u'name' : u'Disk'}
]
```

I want to:

Update IDs of *list_of_dicts1* with the IDs from *list_of_dicts2* only if 'host' and 'name' match with *list_of_dicts2*

And add objects from *list_of_dicts2* to *list_of_dicts1* if there is no object with such 'host' and 'name'

Result:

```
list_of_dicts3 = 
    [
     {u'id' : u'111',
      u'host' : u'host01',
      u'name' : u'Disk'},

     {u'id' : u'444',
      u'host' : u'host02',
      u'name' : u'Disk'},

     {u'id' : u'333',
      u'host' : u'host02',
      u'name' : u'CPU'},

     {u'id' : u'555',
      u'host' : u'host03',
      u'name' : u'Disk'}
    ]
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: is the combination of host and name unique? you may want to use a tuple *(host, name)* as dict key in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
new_list_of_dicts1 = [{a:[c['id'] if c['name'] == i['name'] and c['host'] == i['host'] else i['id'] for c in list_of_dicts2][0] if a == 'id' else b for a, b in i.items()} for i in list_of_dicts1]+[i for i in list_of_dicts2 if not any(b['id'] == i['id'] for b in list_of_dicts1)]
```

Output:

```
{u'host': u'host01', u'id': u'111', u'name': u'Disk'}, {u'host': u'host02', u'id': u'222', u'name': u'Disk'}, {u'host': u'host02', u'id': u'333', u'name': u'CPU'}, {u'host': u'host02', u'id': u'444', u'name': u'Disk'}, {u'host': u'host03', u'id': u'555', u'name': u'Disk'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def mergeLists(list1,list2):
    out = []
    for item1 in list1:
        #find match in list 2 which has same host and item
        match = filter(lambda x:x['host'] == item1['host'] and x['name'] == item1['name'],list2)
        if len(match) > 0:
            #if match found use entry from list 2
            out.append(match[0])
        else:
            #else use item from list 1 as it is unique
            out.append(item1)
    #lastly, add unique entries from list2
    return {v['host']+v['name']:v for v in out+list2}.values()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map those lists of dicts to dicts of dicts and then `update` one with the other:

```
>>> list1_as_dict = collections.OrderedDict(((d["host"],d["name"]), d) for d in list_of_dicts1)
>>> list1_as_dict.update({(d["host"], d["name"]): d for d in list_of_dicts2})
>>> list(list1_as_dict.values())
[{'name': 'Disk', 'id': '111', 'host': 'host01'},
 {'name': 'Disk', 'id': '444', 'host': 'host02'},
 {'name': 'CPU', 'id': '333', 'host': 'host02'},
 {'name': 'Disk', 'id': '555', 'host': 'host03'}]
```

Or shorter, defining a function for extracting the entries; same result:

```
>>> entry = lambda d: ((d["host"], d["name"]), d)
>>> list1_as_dict = collections.OrderedDict(map(entry, list_of_dicts1))
>>> list1_as_dict.update(map(entry, list_of_dicts2))
```

The complexity of this will be O(n).